# Get all pairs in a list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, tuples, combinations

How do I get all possible pairs of items in a list (order not relevant)?

E.g. if I have

```
var list = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

I would like to get these tuples:

```
var pairs = {
   new Tuple(1, 2), new Tuple(1, 3), new Tuple(1, 4),
   new Tuple(2, 3), new Tuple(2, 4)
   new Tuple(3, 4)
}
```

Comment: What is the desired output for the list `{ 1, 1, 1, 1 }`? Six `(1, 1)` or a single `(1, 1)`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Slight reformulation of cgeers answer to get you the tuples you want instead of arrays:

```
var combinations = from item1 in list
                   from item2 in list
                   where item1 < item2
                   select Tuple.Create(item1, item2);
```

(Use `ToList` or `ToArray` if you want.)

In non-query-expression form (reordered somewhat):

```
var combinations = list.SelectMany(x => list, (x, y) => Tuple.Create(x, y))
                       .Where(tuple => tuple.Item1 < tuple.Item2);
```

Both of these will actually consider n<sup>2</sup> values instead of n<sup>2</sup>/2 values, although they'll end up with the correct answer. An alternative would be:

```
var combinations = list.SelectMany((x, i) => list.Skip(i + 1), (x, y) => Tuple.Create(x, y));
```

... but this uses `Skip` which may *also* not be optimized. It probably doesn't matter, to be honest - I'd pick whichever one is most appropriate for your usage.

Comment: Jon, this will create the `Tuple (1,1)`, which is not a pair.

Comment: Thanks, this is the best solution. (but, did you mean `Skip(x.index + 1)`?)

Comment: Yes, the `Except(..)` thing is unnecessary since the `where` clause takes care of that.

Answer (score 4):

Calculate the Cartesian product to determine all the possible combinations.

For example:

```
var combinations = from item in list
                   from item2 in list
                   where item < item2
                   select new[] { item, item2 };
```

You can find more information about calculating a cartesian product using LINQ here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx

You can then convert it to a collection of Tuple objects.

```
var pairs = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
foreach (var pair in combinations)
{
    var tuple = new Tuple<int, int>(pair[0], pair[1]);
    pairs.Add(tuple);
}
```

Or in short:

```
var combinations = (from item in list
                    from item2 in list
                    where item < item2
                    select new Tuple<int, int>(item, item2)).ToList();
```

Comment: **1.** This will create an enumerable of lists. Is that really what you meant? Why not just `select Tuple.Create(item, item2)`? **2.** This will result in duplicate pairs, e.g. `(1,4)` and `(4,1)`. Not sure if that's what the OP wants, but it doesn't look like it.

Comment: It will also create `(1,1)`, which is not stated in the OPs example and is not a pair. But I wonder if the the `(1,4)` and `(4,1)` thing is important.

Comment: @stakx @Mikael All the duplicates can be filtered out by `where item < item2`.

Comment: Thx for the feedback. Updated my answer to filter out the duplicates.

Comment: @Laroslav Only if the items are in order to begin with, right?

Comment: @Mikael, I don't think so, since if the predicate fails for one combination, it will succeed for the other (where the items are swapped around).

Comment: @cgeers, you are still selecting an array mate. Your result will be `IEnumberable<anononymous[]>`

Answer (score 2):

You could solve it like this:

```
 var list = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

 var pairs = from l1 in list
             from l2 in list.Except(new[] { l1 })
             where l1 < l2
             select new { l1, l2 };

 foreach (var pair in pairs)
 {
    Console.WriteLine(pair.l1 + ", " + pair.l2);
 }
```