# Convert loop to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list

A list of Equity Analytics (stocks) objects doing a calculation for daily returns.
Was thinking there must be a pairwise solution to do this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sdata.Count; i++){
    sdata[i].DailyReturn = (i > 0) ? (sdata[i-1].AdjClose/sdata[i].AdjClose) - 1
                                   : 0.0;
}
```

Comment: i don't know, you're doing logicbased on `sdata[i-1]` seems like it'd be pretty difficult to do a linq query to simulat that

Comment: Why do you want to convert it to Linq. Cool?

Comment: @L.B. LINQ!!!!!! I got to have one of those! LINQ! OMG!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new to LINQ, I started using it because of stackoverflow so I tried to play with your question, and I know this may attract downvotes but I tried and it does what you want in case there is at least one element in the list.

```
sdata[0].DailyReturn = 0.0;
sdata.GetRange(1, sdata.Count - 1).ForEach(c => c.DailyReturn = (sdata[sdata.IndexOf(c)-1].AdjClose / c.AdjClose) - 1);
```

But must say that avoiding for loops isn't the best practice. from my point of view, LINQ should be used where convenient and not everywhere. Good old loops are sometimes easier to maintain.

Comment: `GetRange:` _Creates a shallow copy of a range of elements in the source List_ It doesn't change the List, unlike for loop.

Comment: all cautions are good advice but this was more of learning thing. there are certainly functional languages that could implement a similar method more efficiently, like say F#. not changing the list but creating a new one is the functional way.

Comment: Hm,I don't know why would you even create a new list. This is c# and it's not functional. Stay with the loops,that's how it should be implemented.

Comment: see above sticking with orig code. beg to differ about c# not being functional any language can be funcional and c# has already added features to facilitate that.

Comment: was looking for something more like this:[TS answer to how get pairs in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7242116/566879)

Answer (score 2):

*LINQ* stands for: *"Language-Integrated **Query**"*.

LINQ should not be used and almost can't be used for assignments, LINQ doesn't change the given IEnumerable parameter but creates a new one.

As suggest in a comment below, there is a way to **create a new IEnumerable** with LINQ, it will be slower, and a lot less readable.

Though LINQ is nice, an important thing is to know when not to use it.

Just use the good old *for loop*.

Comment: That's untrue. There exists an extension to IEnumerable<T> which also allows you to use the index. The awkwardness would come from the fact that the action performed each iteration is an assignment.

Comment: @DoomMuffins. He needs `Foreach` and then to get the index for every element, you're right, I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: @L.B. Not getting how you want to CHANGE the `sdata` IEnumerable without `ForEach`. `Select` creates a new IEnumerable, not modify the existing one.

Comment: `enumerable.Select((item, index) => { sdata[index].DailyReturn = something; return anothething; });` Of course very ugly...

Comment: @gdoron the code will stay in production as is, or at least as a for loop. just wanted to explore the possibility, where's the harm?